# Successful login allows user to see information otherwise an Alert View is Displayed

Tags: ios7, authentication, xcode5

I'm trying to implement code that only certain users can access. So when the username enters their name in the 'username' textfield it will return the values in the UITableView. When I sign in using username it won't display the array and displays the alert. What am I doing wrong? usernameText is the outlet into the storyboard.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

// Return the number of rows in the section.

LoginViewController *userInfo = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];



if ([userInfo.usernameTxt.text isEqualToString:@"username"])
{
    _loginSuccess = [flashesArray count];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Access Denied" message:@"Please Sign Up For This Services" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
return _loginSuccess;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues in your code:

1. You've created a new instance for 'LoginViewController'. That means 'userInfo.usernameTxt.text' is always empty. You have to pass the Loginname from your LoginViewController to the controller which handles the table.
2. You compare the loginname always with @"username". I think you want to compare with a real loginname